# iOS xcdatamodel newly added attribute has quotation mark

Tags: ios, core-data, core-data-migration, xcdatamodel

I just migrated my new data model and added a new attribute called "author_mail".However I discover at when I output my records:

```
attachments = "<relationship fault: 0xd2459c0 'attachments'>";
author = nil;
"author_mail" = nil; <-- ABNORMAL
category1 = World;
```

I set the author_mail to string type but I don't think the author_mail should wrap with quotation mark. I don't know if it related to my migration but it does not output any error. 
Any clue where should I start look on? I found nothing on the internet.

Result I want:

```
attachments = "<relationship fault: 0xd2459c0 'attachments'>";
author = nil;
author_mail = nil; 
category1 = World;
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not abnormal, and it does not mean what you think it means. Relax, nothing is wrong.

What you're seeing is the result of calling `description` on `NSManagedObject`. By default, this is how `NSManagedObject` formats the result. If a key name contains any non-alphanumeric characters, it puts quote marks around the key name. That's just how they decided to do it. As a result:

- This only affects the result of calling `description` on the object, which is what happens if you call `NSLog` to print the object.
- This does not indicate that the quote marks are part of the key name. If you try to set a value for `author_name`, you'll find that you should not include the quotes, because they're not part of the name.

**This has no effect on anything aside from printing the objects using the `description` method.**

You can *and should* just ignore this.

If it really bothers you for some reason, create your own subclass of `NSManagedObject` and override the `description` method. Make it print whatever you want, with whatever formatting you want.

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply! I'm worry because I always get nil value to author_mail from xml even though the other fields appear to be just fine.

Comment: If you post a new question about that, someone may be able to help.